# css background-image will not work

Tags: css, background-image

I've been patient with this, it is..

```
aside{
        width: 300px;
        margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
        padding: 5px;
        background-image:url ("images/simple_dashed_@2X.png");
        position:relative;
        float: right;
        height: 800px;
        border: solid #002222; 
        color: #bab1b1;
        text-align:center;
    }
```

the images folder is in the same folder as the .html file. I did also try (".../images/simple_dashed_@2X.png") I have also checked and rechecked the name of the picture it's correct capitalization and all. It just shows nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds from your overall level of confusion over the problem that you are not using your Chrome developer tools properly.

You can use the Inspector to determine beyond a shadow of a doubt if the image is not loading, is simply off screen, etc.

Please watch this video where JavaScript's Batman, Paul Irish, explains:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O3W1yuq-ZlE

I guarantee you will be able to solve the problem on your own after watching this video for about 20 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Image references are relative to the *CSS* file, not your *HTML* document. Can you adjust your image path accodingly?

So, if your files are laid out like:

```
/
 page.html
 /assets
  /CSS
    styles.css
 /images
    simple_dashed_@2X.png
```

your style should be:

```
 background-image:url ("../../images/simple_dashed_@2X.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

`background-image:url ("images/simple_dashed_@2X.png");`

with

```
background-image:url("images/simple_dashed_@2X.png");
```

Get out the space after url, and it should work again.

Js fiddle-> http://jsfiddle.net/niteshp27/XMUmq/

Comment: It worked, thank you so much. I'm obviously very new to this.